# Enabling openssl With PHP/nginx

Tags: nginx, smtp, php5, openssl

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to SMTP + SSL through PHP using nginx + PHP 5,

```
Could not connect to smtp host 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com' (5) (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
```

In phpinfo I see:

```
OpenSSL support     disabled (install ext/openssl)
```

This leads me to believe I've installed OpenSSL incorrectly.

I've read a bunch of places where I should uncomment the following line:

```
extension = php_openssl.dll
```

This line does not exist so I added it to the end of my php.ini to no avail. The php_openssl.dll file does not exist anywhere on my server.

Answer (score 1):

The line you are mentioning indeed does activate the openssl PHP-Extension on Windows Machines - though i doubt you are running nginx on Windows.

extension=openssl.so loads the openssl extension on my Box, you need to have PHP compiled with openssl Support:

```
--with-openssl[=DIR]
```

or/and advise the Package Management of your Distro to build the Extension at all/correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> The php_openssl.dll file does not exist anywhere on my server

Then you need to install it (it also requires a compatible openSSL installation). Peering into my crystal ball I see that you are running on MSWindows - did you use a packaged installation for PHP? If so which one?

The binary distribution from php.net includes the php stub dll - if it's not on your machine you may need to reinstall php. Then [install openssl](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) and enable loading of the extension.

Alternatively you could just route the SMTP traffic via [stud](https://github.com/bumptech/stud#readme)/[stunnel](http://www.marshallsoft.com/stunnel_manual.htm)